# Jquery form validation won't work when I integrate Jquery Date Picker

Tags: javascript

When I don't use the Jquery Plugin it works but when I use it, it does not work. I have researched for a solution and am yet to solve it.

The HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Place Advert</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test/css/style.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="runnable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Load jQuery and the validate plugin -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .auto-style2 {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 1px 4px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</h1>
    <h1 class="auto-style1">Sign Up</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

        <div class="auto-style1" style="height: 67px">
            <br />
            I am looking to<br />
            <br />
            <select name="AdvertType" id='purpose'>
                <option id="AccountType" selected="selected" value="Buy">Buy</option>
                <option id="AccountType" value="Sell">Sell</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>

        <div id="layer4" style="position: absolute; width: 750px; height: 366px; z-index: 4; left: 25%; top: 150px" class="auto-style2">

            <br />

            <br />
            &nbsp; Enter In A Produce Name: 
            <input name="ProduceName" type="text" />&nbsp; 
            Enter In A Produce Category: 
            <input name="ProduceCategory" type="text" />
            <br />
            <br />
            Enter In A Headline: 
            <input name="ProduceHeadline" type="text" id="EmailAddress" style="width: 290px" />
            <br />
            <br />
            Buy/Sell Price (Per KG): 
            <input name="Price" type="text" id="BusinessName" style="width: 40px" />
            Quantity Wanted/Avaliable: 
            <input name="Weight" type="text" style="width: 40px" />
            KG
            <br />
            <div id='business'>
                <br />
                From
                <input name="From" type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
                To 
            <input name="To" type="text" id="txtToDate" />
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />
            <span lang="en-gb">
                <textarea class="auto-style3" name="ProduceTags" rows="2" style="width: 547px" cols="20" id="word_count"></textarea>
                <br />
                <br />
                Total word count: <span id="display_count">0</span> words. Words left: <span id="word_left">5</span>&nbsp;
            <br />
                <br />
                <input name="Register" type="submit" value="Register" onclick="getwords()" />
    </form>
    <div id="layer7" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index: 7; top: 680px; width: 100%; height: 40px" class="auto-style1">
        <br />
        Designed by Rajan Flora
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Java Script Code:

I have added the rules for the form, they worked fine before I added the Jquery Date Plugin. The form validation does not work when the Date Plugin was added. After doing further research online I can still not overcome the the issue and require assistance.

```
<script>

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please only enter Characters");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("spaceAllowed", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z , (" ")]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please only enter Characters");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("numbersonly", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please only enter Numbers");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("postcode1", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid UK postcode and ensure there are no spaces");

</script>

<script>

    // When the browser is ready...
    $(function () {

        // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
        $("#register-form").validate({

            // Specify the validation rules
            rules: {

                ProduceName: {
                    required: true,
                },

                ProduceCategory: {
                    required: true,
                },

                ProduceHeadline: {
                    required: true,
                },

            },

            // Specify the validation error messages
            messages: {

            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });

    });

</script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
            }
        });
        $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Are there Javascript errors when you add the Date Plugin and the page loads?  Often times an error will break all the Javascript on the page.

Comment: please clean/indent your code and add `JQuery` and `datepicker` tag ; + make a http://jsfiddle.net/ if you can

Comment: I can't seem to find any, everything was working fine until I added in the actual script code and libraries which I acquired from a website. I ran the code in a separate file and it worked fine.

Comment: The JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjbdqvac/2/

Answer (score 2):

The reason it do not work is because you include jQuery many times on the page.
Usually you only include one version of jQuery on the page.
I have removed all but one in your example and then in started to work.
The datepicker logic seemed ok.

```
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
      $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
  });
  $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
      $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
  });
```

[modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjbdqvac/3/)